# Алгоритм нарезки прямоугольника на равные меньшие прямоугольники

Tags: алгоритм, геометрия

Дан исходный прямоугольник N×M.
Задача: определить сколько раз можно полностью "уложить" (ориентация любая) меньший прямоугольник n×m в исходный.
Возможно, для будущих ходоков будет интересно КАК.
Спасибо.

Comment: Интересный вопрос, не решал раньше.

[Тут](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/210979/Fast-optimizing-rectangle-packing-algorithm-for-bu) с картинками рассматривают упаковку прямоугольников разных размеров в минимальную площадь.

С идентичными — наверное один раз пройтись по всем точкам контейнера, вставляя каждый раз, когда возможно, очередной экземпляр, пробуя его вертикально/горизонтально. Может, сделать всё-таки два прохода. Один с приоритетом вертикальной ориентации, второй - горизонтальной. Оставить выигравшего.

Comment: ну по ссылке решают посложнее задачу. я б вашу задачу решал таким образом:
1) используя площадь большого прямоугольника `N x M` и площядь маленького `n x m` я б посчитал максимально-допустимое количество вхождений - S
2) дальше условно можно разделить прямоугольник 'N x M' на сетку 'x, y' (где x, y количество ячеек по горизонтали/вертикали), - в каждой ячейке сетки маленький прямоугольник может находится в 2х состояниях - горизонтальное/вертикальное (получается что-то на подобии дерева с булинами на каждой ветке)
3) делаем рекурсию перебор всех вариантов для каждой "логической ячейки"

Comment: 4) лучший результат храним вне рекурсивной функции
5) условия выхода из рекурсии:
    a) результат (количество прямоугольник - ака "логических ячеек") больше равное числу S

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Задачка решается просто.

Если нужен ответ на вопрос КАК

```
// Возвращает массив расположения блоков [ { x, y, w, h } ]
function calc(W, H, w, h) {

    var hor = pack([], W, H, w, h, 0, 0);
    var ver = pack([], W, H, h, w, 0, 0);

    // сортировка блоков в порядке сверху-вниз, слева-направо
    // если не планируется нумеровать блоки - можно удалить
    return (hor.length >= ver.length ? hor : ver).sort(function(a, b) {
        return (a.y - b.y) || (a.x - b.x);
    });

    function pack(pieces, W, H, w, h, x0, y0) {
        var x, y;
        var nx = W / w | 0;  // число блоков, умещающееся по ширине
        var ny = H / h | 0;  // по высоте
        var n = nx * ny;     // всего
        for (y = 0; y < ny; y++) for (x = 0; x < nx; x++) {
            pieces.push({ x: x0 + x*w, y: y0 + y*h, w: w, h: h });
        }
        if (W % w >= h && H >= w) {  // осталось полезное место справа
            pack(pieces, W % w, H, h, w, x0 + nx*w, 0);
        } else if (H % h >= w && W >= h) {  // осталось полезное место снизу
            pack(pieces, W, H % h, h, w, 0, y0 + ny*h);
        }
        return pieces;
    }

}
```

Если нужен ответ на вопрос СКОЛЬКО

```
// Возвращает число блоков
function calc(W, H, w, h) {

    return Math.max(pack(W, H, w, h), pack(W, H, h, w));

    function pack(W, H, w, h) {
        var n = (W / w | 0) * (H / h | 0);
        if (W % w >= h && H >= w) {
            n += pack(W % w, H, h, w);
        } else if (H % h >= w && W >= h) {
            n += pack(W, H % h, h, w);
        }
        return n;
    }

}
```

Демо: http://jsfiddle.net/RHq23/

Comment: Лаконично и красиво! Результат тот же, что у меня в варианте с приоритетом "горизонтальных" ([скрин](https://www.dropbox.com/s/r06im7qxcr3pvlr/Screenshot%202014-02-23%2019.31.55.png)).

Это, как я понимаю, мы реализовывали алгоритм Shelf (книжной полки). Интересно попробовать что-то чуть более сложное, типа циклически закрученного паркета, с единственной "дыркой" в центре, например.

Answer (score 2):

Чистая эвристика: сделал [модель с простым перебором](http://jsfiddle.net/sergiks/sbTE4/) на JS. В очередную точку пробует поставить блок гор. или верт. Есть вариант с приоритетом вертикального положения, есть с приоритетом горизонтального.

Добавил случайность: каждый раз с вероятностью 50% выбирается приоритет гор. или вертикального расположения очередного блока. С откатом на оставшийся вариант, если «приоритетный» не влезает.

Забавно: наблюдаю, что с «хаосом» иногда получаются результаты **лучшие**, чем когда выбран определённый вариант приоритета. Т.е. оптимум лежит в более сложном алгоритме.

Для размера «гаража» 320x278 и «машины» 12x56 я пока поймал максимум в 125:
[image: max=125]

P.s. потыкав и понаблюдав расстановки, интуитивно понял, что надо начинать из углов, двигаясь к центру. Если кому не лень форкнуть и разобраться, дайте знать. Может, конкурс устроить? Битву алгоритмов : )   Все пишут свои варианты. В назначенный день объявляем конкурсный размер гаража и машины, и смотрим, кто найдёт максимум за меньшее время.

Comment: Сергей, спасибо за предложенное решение. Внедрил в качестве "лучше чем ничего". Смущает наличие рандома. Несовершенство такого подхода очевидно, например, на значениях `P.init(250,120,50,30);`. Всё-таки вариант с постоением дерева был бы предпочтительнее.

Comment: @disfated в частном случае, где точно вписывается, действительно лушче работает один из "фиксированных" вариантов алгоритма: в  примере P.init(250,120,50,30); [идеально срабатывает](https://www.dropbox.com/s/peo8z4euvea7dmt/Screenshot%202014-02-23%2015.57.42.png) "сначала вертикальные".

Так что "рабочим" вариантом я бы предложил пробовать три вещи: фикс.верт.,  фикс.гор. и рандом.  Брать лучшего : )